# Data duplication in Mogodb- Rails - Mongomapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongomapper

I am developing a facebook application in Ruby on Rails using MongoDB as database.

This application is for bookmarking facebook links.

Now I am facing a problem with MongoDB. Due to its "fire and forget" property, I am getting lot of duplicate URLs. I am unable to check whether the data is inserted or not. When we insert records continuosly i am unable to check whether the data exist  or not to avoid duplication. Before the insertion  of URL, it is unable to check whether the URL already exists.

I am using MongoMapper and Rails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to verify that data was inserted, you can use the :safe option, as such:

```
foo.save(safe: true)
```

See http://mongomapper.com/documentation/plugins/safe.html

I'm not sure if this waits for the write to propagate to all cluster nodes. MongoDB supports this as well, but I'm not sure if Mongomapper does.